# xmpp with openfire client connection lost suddently with smack 4.1

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack

I am working with the `XMPPTCPConnection` to connect with my openfire server, Connected successfully and sent/receive data packets successfully. Connection remains stable but suddenly drops with an exception and I am getting no clue about this exception. 
My server disconnect idle user time is 60 sec. And I have implemented all ping manager, and re-connection code. So its reconnecting but not getting why it get disconnected with exception or how to resolve this exception.

```
 E/MainService: Connection to XMPP server was lost.org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException: Parser got END_DOCUMENT event. This could happen e.g. if the server closed the connection without sending a closing stream element 
 07-28 10:21:22.003 12719-16068/com.thatsit.android D/SMACK:
 XMPPConnection closed due to an exception (0)
 07-28 10:21:22.003 12719-16068/com.thatsit.android W/System.err: org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException: Parser got END_DOCUMENT event. This could happen e.g. if the server closed the connection without sending a closing stream element

 07-28 10:21:22.003 12719-16068/com.thatsit.android W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1170)

07-28 10:21:22.003 12719-16068/com.thatsit.android W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$300(XMPPTCPConnection.java:952)
07-28 10:21:22.003 12719-16068/com.thatsit.android W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:967)
07-28 10:21:22.013 12719-16068/com.thatsit.android W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Any help will be highly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to disconnect ideal users.

If you again disconnect then make a service that is working in background and check the xmpp connection every 10 seconds.If connected then there is no need to connect but if disconnect then connect it to server again. I have handled this from my app.

I have also open source code on [github](https://github.com/saveendhiman/XMPPSample_Studio).If you want then you can refer from there.

This is not updated code with 4.1 but i have already made changes but need to upload. Today evening i'll upload updated code.

Thanks, Hope this will help to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are two issues related to yours: one is in Openfire 4.x.x and one is in the Smack 4.0.7 library.

There is a bug (OF-1308) in Openfire 4.x.x and above that when the server disconnects a client, it doesn't send the end-tag of stream to the client as an intentional disconnection.  It just closes the socket and causes PacketReader getting END_DOC event.

In Smack, the PacketReader handles IOException (unexpected loss of network connectivity), end-tag of stream (an intentional disconnection), or END_DOC (unexpected disconnection from server like server crashed.)  Getting IOException will trigger Reconnection Manager if it is enabled.  Getting an end-tag of stream will trigger normal connection close event. However, Smack treats the END_DOC as getting end-tag of stream. In my opinion, Smack should treat END_DOC as IOException since the end-tag of stream has not been received.

There is another twist. If you have compression enabled, PacketReader gets IOException if the server simply closes the socket.  If compression is disabled, PacketReader gets END_DOC if the server simply closes the socket.

In your case, when there is an idle timeout enabled, the client should not trigger ReconnectionManager.  Otherwise, it defeats the purpose of idle timeout.  I am testing my fix, so I haven't reported the Smack bug to the Ignite Community yet.